# Why does collect() take so long when a specific testcase in a specific testing file/module is specified?

Tags: python, pytest

For a commandline that is completely specific on which testcase to run - down to the specific combination of input values in `@pytest.mark.parametrize` :

```
--target processor/test_batch_feed_processor.py::TestBatchFeedProcessor.test_azsql_watermark_diff_extractor[False-False-trigger_start_time3]
```

Why would `collect()` stage taking tens of seconds and up to several minutes?

```
/Users/stephenboesch/git/cscp/src/framework/venv/bin/python3 /Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/plugins/python/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py --multiprocess --qt-support=auto --client 127.0.0.1 --port 60639 --file /Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/plugins/python/helpers/pycharm/_jb_pytest_runner.py --target processor/test_batch_feed_processor.py::TestBatchFeedProcessor.test_azsql_watermark_diff_extractor[False-False-trigger_start_time3] -- --rootdir=. --jb-show-summary 
Connected to pydev debugger (build 223.8214.51)
Launching pytest with arguments --rootdir=. ddex/processor/test_batch_feed_processor.py::TestBatchFeedProcessor::test_azsql_watermark_diff_extractor[False-False-trigger_start_time3] in /Users/stephenboesch/git/cscp/src/framework/tests

============================= test session starts ==============================
platform darwin -- Python 3.10.12, pytest-7.4.0, pluggy-1.2.0 -- /Users/stephenboesch/git/cscp/src/framework/venv/bin/python3
cachedir: .pytest_cache
rootdir: /Users/stephenboesch/git/cscp/src/framework/tests
configfile: ../pytest.ini
plugins: cov-4.1.0, mock-3.11.1, nunit-1.0.3, azurepipelines-1.0.4
collecting ...
```

Is a bunch of python source and testing code being compiled here? If so, do we have a chance to know *which* modules `pytest` is deciding to compile?  Also in that case, why is `collect()` slow *every* time instead of just the first one?